# preventing the form submission with javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am working on a project , the situation is , the client has to enter the details , and after he enters the details , with java script ( confirm dialogue ) , i m showing all the important details for verification , then when he press ok, the form get submitted.

this is what i have made , but seems it is not working... need help ...

( after pressing cancel .. the dialog box keeps on coming .. and worst part is finally the form get submitted even if i have selected cancel )

( i have removed other details ...)

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function validateMyForm()
{
    var X=confirm("ARE DETAILS CORRECT ??");
  if(!X)
  { 
    alert("validation failed false");
    returnToPreviousPage();
    return false;
  }
else
 {alert("validations passed");
  return true;}
}
</script>





<form name="frm" action=<?php print "new_update_attendence.php"; ?> method="POST"    
id="content" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();">
```

Comment: `var x` and `X` are not equivalent.

Comment: check for errors in `returnToPreviousPage()` what does that function do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

capitalization matters ALOT!

```
var x=confirm("ARE DETAILS CORRECT ??");
if(!X) // change to if(!x)
```

you could do, for second part of your question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateMyForm()
    {
        var X=confirm("ARE DETAILS CORRECT ??");
        if(!X)
        { 
            setTimeout((function(){ window.location.reload(); }), 500);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: changed ... but even after that .. the dialog box keep on coming even if i have selected cancel .

Comment: dialog `validations passed` will show if you hit `OK`, If you Hit `Cancel` will show `validation failed false` and call the `returnToPreviousPage();` function.

Comment: what does `returnToPreviousPage()` do?

Comment: but the dialog box keeps on coming .. even if i press ok or cancel.

Comment: wat to change so that it comes only once .. if ok then form submitted else same page is loaded or retained..

Comment: thanks a million bro .. :) its working now .. i was stupid with lower case .:)

Answer (score 3):

`X` must be in lowerCase :

```
 if(!x)
  { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I gather you've used jQuery in the past. In jQuery `return false` would prevent the form from being submitted all together. That's because jQuery catches that return value (`false`) and translates it into `eventObject.preventDefault(); eventObject.stopPropagation();` whereas `return false`, without jQuery only does the first (preventing the default action of that event). The event still bubbles/propagates.

change your HTML to `onsubmit="return validateMyForm(event);">` to get access to the event object. Then, in JavaScript:

```
function validateMyForm(e)//e should hold the event
{
    e = e || window.event;//except for older IE versions(?), which we correct here
    //do whatever, if the form shouldn't be submitted:
    if (!confirm("ARE DETAILS CORRECT ??"))
    {
        if (e.preventDefault)
        {//chrome, FF, opera, ...
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();//<-- important line here
            return false;
        }//cruddy IE clients
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.cancelBubble = true;//<-- stop event in its tracks
        return false;
    }
}
```

That should do it.